# Unable to change the text color of ListView item

Tags: android

Following the other posts regarding the same topic i implemented the **getView** method of array adapter. But the app is stopping unfortunately due to the highlighted line , because if i comment it out , app doesnt crash. Kindly Help whats wrong : -

```
  aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al) {
                @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
           ***TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1);***
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            return view;
        }
```

Logcat -

04-13 04:48:38.246    2870-2870/com.example.sairav.app3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sairav.app3, PID: 2870
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.sairav.app3.MainActivity$1.getView(MainActivity.java:41)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.onLayout(AbsoluteLayout.java:123)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:494)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

***What needs to be done ? Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `convertView` is null, you need to load a new one.

Tricks:

```
aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al) {
                    @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                        R.layout.fragment_home_drawer_listview_item, null);
                }
                TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setTextColor(getResources.getColor(Color.WHITE));
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return convertView;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling findViewById on the view passed into getView.

Change

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

to

```
TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

Comment: yea , tried it too , still stopping unfortunately ! :(

Comment: Could you post the log

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al) {
                    @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
               ***TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1);***
                tv.setTextColor(getResources.getColor(Color.WHITE));
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                return view;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Logcat , the View variable is NULL because the super.getView did not
return anything.

Can you change your ArrayAdapter creation to this:

```
new ArrayAdapter (context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, list)
{
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ... your code goes here.
  ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in listview using adapter

```
 txtview.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```